# Distinct doesn't work

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database

The below code gives a wrong result. I am using `DISTINCT` command but type appears two times on the results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CONCERT.CONCERT_ID, CONCERT.C_TYPE,  
    COUNT(BOOKINGS.CUSTOMER_CUSTOMER_ID) AS NUMBER_OF_CUSTOMERS
FROM 
    CONCERT, CUSTOMER, EVENT, BOOKINGS
WHERE 
    CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID =  BOOKINGS.CUSTOMER_CUSTOMER_ID
    AND EVENT.EVENT_ID =  BOOKINGS.EVENT_EVENT_ID
    AND CONCERT.CONCERT_ID =  EVENT.CONCERT_ID
GROUP BY 
    CONCERT.CONCERT_ID, CONCERT.C_TYPE
ORDER BY 
    CONCERT.CONCERT_ID DESC;
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: `DISTINCT` returns distinct values of entire cortege.

Comment: maybe GROUP BY doesnt works

Comment: Group By works fine but maybe the way of using that in Oracle is different from other `RDBMS` which you worked later.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 8):

distinct means that the row as a whole should not be duplicated, in your case the type appears twice but with difference concert_id and number_of_customers.

Comment: Its not about your code, its about the approach. DISTINCT checks your output result set and makes sure you have no duplicates by comparing all columns. In your case, the Concert_id and number_of_customers are different for each "pop" type, therefore distinct will not consider them duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `DISTINCT` AND `GROUP BY`. `GROUP BY` already makes it distinct.

You need to tell us which of the rows 10001 or 10000 you want to keep. This one will keep the lowest one.

```
SELECT MAX(CONCERT.CONCERT_ID)  CONCERT_ID, CONCERT.C_TYPE,  
COUNT(BOOKINGS.CUSTOMER_CUSTOMER_ID) AS NUMBER_OF_CUSTOMERS
FROM CONCERT, CUSTOMER, EVENT, BOOKINGS
WHERE CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID =  BOOKINGS.CUSTOMER_CUSTOMER_ID
AND EVENT.EVENT_ID =  BOOKINGS.EVENT_EVENT_ID
AND CONCERT.CONCERT_ID =  EVENT.CONCERT_ID
GROUP BY CONCERT.C_TYPE
ORDER BY CONCERT.CONCERT_ID DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MIN` or `MAX` in your `WHERE` clause to get your aim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COURSE.COURSE_ID, COURSE.TITLE, 
COUNT(ATTENDANCE.STUDENT_ID) AS NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS
FROM ATTENDANCE, OFFERING, COURSE, STUDENT
WHERE OFFERING.OFFERING_ID = ATTENDANCE.OFFERING_ID
AND OFFERING.COURSE_ID = COURSE.COURSE_ID
AND STUDENT.STUDENT_ID = ATTENDANCE.STUDENT_ID
AND COURSE.COURSE_ID IN (SELECT MAX(t1.COURSE_ID) FROM COURSE t1 GROUP BY t1.TITLE)
GROUP BY COURSE.COURSE_ID, COURSE.TITLE
ORDER BY COURSE_ID DESC;
```